# Finding the longest sequence of digits from a string in bash using awk alone

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to find the longest sequence of digits from a string in bash using `awk` alone. I have formed the below command and it is giving me the output.

```
$ echo "This_is_1234_and_44448888_1234567_111111_23456789_and_234" | sed 's/./\n&/g' | awk 'BEGIN{max_length=0} { tmp=match($1,/[0-9]/) ; if (tmp) { numbers[i]=numbers[i]$0;non_digit=0;} else if (non_digit<1) { non_digit=2 ;i++; } } END { i=0; for (key in numbers) { current_length=length(numbers[key]); if (current_length > max_length) { max_length = current_length; i = 0;} if (current_length >= max_length) {i++; max_length_strings[i] = numbers[key];} } print "max_length for the consecutive number portion is ",max_length; for ( j in max_length_strings ) { print "String_Part: " max_length_strings[j] " and Length: " max_length; }}'
max_length for the consecutive number portion is  8
String_Part: 23456789 and Length: 8
String_Part: 44448888 and Length: 8
```

But for getting each character from the string for digit checking, I am using `sed` command.

So how can I avoid this use of sed and achieve the same result by using a single `awk` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just awk:

```
s="This_is_1234_and_44448888_1234567_111111_23456789_and_234"

awk -v RS='[^[:digit:]]+' 'length($0) >= max{
   max=length($0)
   num[max]=(num[max]?num[max] "," $0:$0)
}
END {
   printf "max length=%s, numbers: %s\n", max, num[max]
}' <<< "$s"

max length=8, numbers: 44448888,23456789
```

**Explanation:**

- Using custom `RS='[^[:digit:]]+'` we are making record separator as 1 or more non-digit characters thus each record becomes digit fields
- We are then check length of each record (all digit fields) and keep updating `max` variable in `length($0) >= max` block
- We also keep all the max length fields in `num` array
- In the `END` block we just print `max` and `num` array entry
- This is `gnu-awk` specific due to multi character `RS`

Comment: could you please explain a bit how the code is working with RS

Comment: Added explanation in answer.

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-specific due to the multi-char RS.

Comment: Yes agreed, added in answer.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk 4.* for FPAT and true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FPAT="[0-9]+" }
{
    delete strs
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        cur = length($i)
        strs[cur][$i]
        max = (i>1 && cur>max ? cur : max)
    }
    for (str in strs[max]) {
        printf "String_Part: %s and Length: %d\n", str, max
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
String_Part: 23456789 and Length: 8
String_Part: 44448888 and Length: 8
```

The above assumes you want the output of the max for each input line and not across the whole file. If you do want it across the whole file then, again with GNU awk (for RT):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="[0-9]+" }
{
    cur = length(RT)
    strs[cur][RT]
    max = (NR>1 && cur>max ? cur : max)
}
END {
    for (str in strs[max]) {
        printf "String_Part: %s and Length: %d\n", str, max
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
String_Part: 23456789 and Length: 8
String_Part: 44448888 and Length: 8
```